# Unable to access Wordpress Dashboard with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, wordpress

I am facing a bit of an issue when setting up WordPress with Nginx as reverse proxy to Apache backend.
All the pages are loading, but i get an error when i try to login to wp-admin dashboard.
The error is `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

I have checked my file permissions, database prefix,.htaccess and even usermeta admin privileges in the db, all seem to be perfect.
The site was working perfectly fine before i setup nginx reverse proxy.

Here is my **apache2 config**:

```
   <VirtualHost *:8081>
       DocumentRoot "/mnt/NAS/wp_data/wordpress/"
       ServerName my_site_url
       ServerAlias www.my_site_url
    
    <Directory "/mnt/NAS/wp_data/wordpress/">
       Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
   </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my **apache ports.conf**:

```
   #Listen 80
   Listen 8081
```

Here is my **nginx config**:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my_site_url;

        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name www.my_site_url my_site_url;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }

        ssl_certificate /var/www/mycert/certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/mycert/private.key;
}
```

Last but not least my **wp-config.php** is as default and i haven't added anything else apart from

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) ) {
if ( 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
}
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] ) ) {
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
}
```

Comment: Is it working without the ssl? Also try to put 
`define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`
At the beginning of the config file and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried adding it, didn't make a difference. Btw, i use a custom folder where i have my wordpress directory as shown above. I dont use /var/www/ or /var/www/html, i use /mnt/NAS/wp_data/wordpress directorty. I have added this to apache.conf and also i've chowned it to www-data:www-data. Technically that shouldn't be an issue.

I am unable to login to wp-admin area. It says you are not allowed to access this.
I am however able to use the same folder and same files by removing nginx proxy and just using plain apache as before.
Any more guidance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I've meant to add it to the wp-config.php. If you've added there and the result is still the same, you could try to search for a line like `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);` in the wp-config.php, and if it's there you can try to delete it and see if it helps.

Comment: No luck. Should i just try to use nginx alone for wp instead of the reverse proxy? If so could you please provide me with a sample config with ssl to refer from?

Answer (score 0):

I was able run  Wordpress and its dashboard  on apache with nginx as reverse proxy

the nginx configuration is

```
 location ^~ /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://x.y.x.z/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

and in the wp-config.php (on apache server) the following contents are added

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) ) {
if ( 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
}
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] ) ) {
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
}
```